# Ctrl + Cmd + Return doesn't maximize active pane in iTerm2

Tags: iterm

The split panes functionality is the primary reason why i use iTerm2.

I can maximize/unminimize the active pane by using the View -> Maximize Active Pane menu item.

But nothing happens when I press the Ctrl + Cmd + Return shortcut key combination listed next to the menu item.

I looked through the preferences pane and I didn't find this particular key binding anywhere, which makes me think it's not customizable via the UI.

Any suggestions about what might be wrong or how I could go about fixing this?

Answer (score 6):

D'oh; the problem was that I was confusing the Shift key (depicted as ⇧) with the Ctrl key (depicted as ⌃).

So, the correct combination is Shift + Cmd + Return.